# Make fixture params be a list of fixtures from a different file

Tags: python, pytest

I want to be able to create a fixture that contains a list of fixtures in the params, like in the code below. Note also that these fixtures are in a different file as well.

Then I want to be able to use this fixture in different tests where it tries one combination at a time.

```py
@pytest.fixture(
       scope="session",
       params=[
           fixture1,
           fixture2,
           fixture3,
       ],
   )
def fixture(request):
   return request.param
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def fixture(request, fixture1, fixture2, fixture3)
    return request.param
``
```

Comment: Did not work for me, says that 'param' is not an attribute of 'request'.